# RCOMClient is not available for R Version 3.6.1

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I've been using RDCOMClient to automatically retrieve an email attachment and move it to a specific folder location.  However since I updated my version of R to 3.6.1 this package is no longer available.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround or better still an alternative.  I've looked but can only really find solutions in sending emails, as opposed to retrieving them?

***Warning*** in install.packages :

> package ‘RDComClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
>   outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application") Error in
>   COMCreate("Outlook.Application") : could not find function "COMCreate"

Comment: Have you tried installing from the Omegahat repository: `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")`?

Comment: I have, it still returns the same error.  I was considering a further solution, in changing the version of R back for that specific script.  I wonder if this can be done?

Comment: Sure, you can have multiple versions of R installed. To use a specific version of R for this script, you'd just need to know where the binary for the specific version you're using is, then from the command prompt you can run something like `C:\path\to\Rscript.exe scriptname.R`. If you're wanting to do it from RStudio, you can check out [their how-to article on that](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this approach.